# cURL Script. Gets 400 error sometimes. Any suggestions?

Tags: php, curl

Sometimes this code works (200 http code) and other times it gets a 400 http code. This is with the same symbol in the url. Currently that is hard coded. So the exact same request sometimes fails and other times succeeds.

Is there a way to get the details on the 400 errors?

Wondering if there is anything I can change in the cURL parameters to make it work all the time.

The site is pretty popular, so I imaging there's many servers that process it.

Here is the code:

Page Link: https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RWOD/profile

Actual cURL link: https://backend.otcmarkets.com/otcapi/company/profile/full/RWOD?symbol=RWOD

```
function NewCurl() {
    global
        $OSFLSymb,
        $UseProxy,
        $ProxArr,
        $ProxyAuth,
        $HTTPStatus
    ;
    
    $NewCurlHandle = curl_init();

    $NewUrl = 'https://backend.otcmarkets.com/otcapi/company/profile/full/' . $OSFLSymb . '?symbol=' . $OSFLSymb;
//  $NewUrl = 'https://backend.otcmarkets.com/otcapi/corp-actions/tier-changes?route=tier-changes&page=1&pageSize=40&retainPageSize=true';
    
        
    curl_setopt ($NewCurlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $NewUrl);
// ********* Try Code
    curl_setopt($NewCurlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

//  ********* End Try Code

    curl_setopt_array( $NewCurlHandle, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => [
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0',
          'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
          'Origin: https://www.otcmarkets.com',
          'Connection: keep-alive',
          'Referer: https://www.otcmarkets.com/',
          'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty',
          'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors',
          'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site',
          'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
        ],
    ] ); 
    If ($UseProxy) {
        // Choose a random proxy
        $CurrProxy = $ProxArr[array_rand($ProxArr)];    // Select a random proxy from the array and assign to $CurrProxy variable
        curl_setopt($NewCurlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $CurrProxy);    // Set CURLOPT_PROXY with proxy in $proxy variable
        curl_setopt($NewCurlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $ProxyAuth);
    }
    
    $CurlPageNew = curl_exec( $NewCurlHandle );
    $HTTPStatus = curl_getinfo($NewCurlHandle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//  ************ Echo HTTP Code 
    echo "<P>HTTP Code: $HTTPStatus"; 
    echo "<BR>Proxy: $CurrProxy";
    $cURLError = curl_error($NewCurlHandle);
    echo "<BR>cURL Error: $cURLError";  
    curl_close($NewCurlHandle);
    return $CurlPageNew;
}
```

Z

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is it possible that some of the time in your code `$OSFLSymb` is not defined with the value you expect? That could potentially lead the remote server to respond with something like 400 Bad Request, because it would cause the URL to be incorrect.

Comment: The Symbol is correct and the page exists. Right now the script is hard coded for just one symbol: RWOD and sometimes works and other times doesn't. Wondering if I can change something in the cURL options or something that perhaps some servers find objectionable..

Comment: I'd pay somebody to make this work: zardiw@gmail.com .......Z

Comment: We dont do paid private work here. The best thing might be to put curl in verbose mode and collect logs of all the requests. Then over time you can analyse data from successful and unsuccessful requests and compare them. I'd say though that with an intermittent fault like this it's probably most likely some network issue or a fault on the server which processes the requests